# Count the number of lattice paths from (0,0) to (x,y) in recursion

Tags: c, recursion

Does anyone know how can i write a recursive function that gets unsigned integers x, y and returns how many paths are to the point x,y from 0,0 in C??

there is only one step every time: up or right.
The limit of the steps are in the rectangle:
(0,0), (0, x), (0,y), (x,y)

Comment: If only +x and +y moves are allowed, you don't need recursion

Comment: Please, add more info about your topic. What programming language, what data, etc...

Comment: If all +x, -x, +y, -y are allowed, you need the map size as well

Comment: Look into the pascal's triangle then.

Comment: This is trivial to implement recursively - if you don't mind terrible performance. If you want something faster, look for other methods.

Comment: it's a question at homework.. they ask to do it recursively...
but i don't know how..

Comment: @enrey He says it's in C in the tags.

Comment: yeah i also edited the question and added that it's in C

Comment: well, `pathsTo(x,y) = pathsTo(x-1,y) + pathsTo(x,y-1)` + some border cases

Comment: The homework tag is obsolete. Please don't add it

Comment: sorry, didn't know..
and thanks for the help, but  what do you mean by border cases?

Comment: @AnatEliahu border cases = `x==0 || y==0`

Comment: yeah it works.. thank you! now i'll try to understand why...

Comment: In javascript: `function pt(x,y){return !(x&&y)||(pt(x-1,y)+pt(x,y-1))}`

Comment: @samoz I know, he added it later

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, this isn't C, but you should understand it very well.. Whatever starts with dollar is a variable, the rest is similar.

```
function path($x, $y){
    if($x==0 && $y==0){ /* && is logical AND operator */
        return 1;
    // here's first (and only) edge case. If X and Y is 0, that means were are already where we want to be. We assume there's one path from the position you are on to the same position you are on.
    }

    $count=0;

    if($x>0){
        $count+=path($x-1, $y); // Here, we ask how many paths go from position (x-1, y) to zero, if the X is not zero already..
    }
    if($y>0){
        $count+=path($x, $y-1); // here same stuff for Y, if Y is not zero, let's recurse into (x, y-1)
    }

    return $count; // in those conditions above, the result is added into COUNT variable
}

$x=6; 
$y=4; // some input


print path($x, $y); // here it all starts, with the original input numbers
```

There's no math behind it, it's a recursion. In each run of the path() function, the path function runs another instance of the path function, and that runs another and that runs another.... Always with the position one less than current, in one dimension and then one less in the other dimension. Only if the recursion already reached the (0,0) position, it will return 1, which will be added to the count variable in previous instance, that will be added to count variable in yet previous instance, and so on and so on, until it returns that to the print function.

Note: the function doesn't go from (0,0) to (x,y) but from (x,y) to (0,0). But the result is the same.

Comment: I added a bit of explanation for you, let me know if it helps. You should do some research about what recursion is. It's basicaly loop with a stack.

Comment: thank you, I understand what recursion is, but I don't know the logic behind this solution..
I would have never thought about this myself..

Comment: From each position, wherever it is, you can go only up or right. So, from each position, there are two whole sets of possible ways, one starts up, one starts right. That's those two path() callings inside the path() function. Those two IF's are there, because you don't want to go further up or right if you are on the edge of the rectangle already. On each position, the function asks "whats the sum of possible paths from position one up from here plus number of paths from position one right from here", and this repeats until it hits the target and returns 1. From there, all the returns sum up.

Comment: The return that sums up then says "how many times it's sub-recursions hit the target". Actualy I made it go from (x,y) to (0,0), so it is going down and left, but it gives the same result. Just read it carefully and you will get it. Recursion isn't hard to understand, it's just hard to explain.

Answer (score 2):

A Java solution :

```
/**
 * Compute the number of ways you can get from 0,0 to x,y
 *
 * @param x grid width
 * @param y grid height
 * @return number of lattice paths
 */
public long compute(int x, int y) {
    // there's only 1 way you can reach a point which is on some edge
    if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    /* Otherwise apply back recursion, i.e. take the last step (when you reach x,y) :
    you can get there only by moving from x-1,y (right) or from x,y-1 (up).
    So the result would be the number of ways you can get to x-1,y plus the number 
    of ways you can get to x,y-1 */
    return compute(x - 1, y) + compute(x, y - 1);
}
```

As the area of the grid grows (x and y) the algorithm become very slow, because you compute the same value a lot of times due to the recursion, so you might want to cache :

```
Map<Pair, Long> cache = new HashMap<>();

public long compute(int x, int y) {
    Pair pair = new Pair(x, y);
    if (cache.containsKey(pair)) {
        return cache.get(pair);
    }
    if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    long result = compute(x - 1, y) + compute(x, y - 1);
    cache.put(pair, result);
    return result;
}
```

Pair is a simple POJO following the [equals() and hashCode() Contract](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/07/java-equals-and-hashcode-contract/).